# Can we delete list which contains different SObjects with one DML statement?

Tags: sobject, dml, delete

I have List which can contains Accounts and Contacts ;
Can we delete the list using just ?

```
List<SObject> testList; 
delete testList;
```

Can we delete list which contains different SObjects with one DML statement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to delete mixed objects in the same list. There is a limit of 10 "chunks" of 200 records if you do this. A chunk is defined as records of the same type (e.g. all Contacts in consecutive order). The appropriate triggers will all execute in chunk order. Doing this has a smaller limit (no more than effectively 2,000 records), but also consumes fewer DML statements (limit of 150 per transaction) than deleting each type at a time.